# Should I, and how to, add methods to int in python?

Tags: python, class, oop, methods, int

(This is a learning related question, so any advice in why should I do or not do anything, as well as recommended resources to get these things better, are more than wellcome.)

I'm trying to learn about OOP in python, and have done a simple "Time" class like this:

```
class Time(object):

    """A time representation."""

    def __init__(self, hours=0, minutes=0, seconds=0):
        self.hours = hours
        self.minutes = minutes
        self.seconds = seconds

    def __int__(self):
        return self.hours * 3600 + self.minutes * 60 + self.seconds
```

Now, that **__*int*__** method lets me get an int from my "Time" instances that represent the time (but in seconds) when I do `int(Time(3, 4, 5))`. I find that to be kind of awesome, by the way. But, in order to use this, it would be nice to know how to make an "int" have a new method that returns a "Time" object, so something like `3643.time()` could be done.

Why?
For various reasons:

1. Because that way I learn about what for me is like black magic right now. (these underscored things that make things happen... and related stuff)
2. Because I don't know why I shouldn't. (so tell me please)

I suppose I could do something like the following outside any class:

```
def time(seconds):
    """Return an HH:MM:SS stamp of "seconds", where "seconds" should be an int."""
    hours, minutes = 0, 0
    if seconds >= 3600:
        hours, seconds = divmod(int, 3600)
    if seconds >= 60:
        minutes, seconds = divmod(int, 60)
    return "{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}".format(hours, minutes, seconds)
```

But that doesn't seem to relate to these objects enough, It doesn't seem that much object oriented... So, I reckon maybe there is a better way to approach this kind of thing.

Comment: In my opinion, unless the object represents a plain numerical quantity, providing an `__int__` method is probably a Bad Idea. (In your example, I think the semantics of calling `int()` on a Time to get seconds since midnight is confusing).

Comment: You shouldn't and you can't (without cheating at least). Reasons why not include namespacing (what happens if another module also adds a `int.time` method?), separation of concerns (why should an int know how to convert itself into your class?), the fact that it's unnecessary, the non-obviousness of `10 .time()`, that you have to write `10 .time()` instead of `10.time()` because of a lexer quirk, the general hackiness (unreliability, obscurity) of any possible implementation, and the fact that Rubyist do it ;-)

Comment: Also, something not feeling OO is not necessarily a bad thing. Python allows you to mix and match OOP and good old procedural programming, to avoid getting lost in the [kingdom of nouns](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html).

Comment: Oh, and another thing: If the `Time` class is not just an example or for learning, forget about it. Time is **hard**, and the existing solutions (e.g. the `datetime` module) are better in virtually every sense of the word.

Comment: @delnan Thanks, it is for learning. You gave me what I really wanted, concepts to look at.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you cannot really add methods to int.  You *could* subclass int, and return that from your `__int__` method, but that won't help you much, since calling `int()` on that will still return a regular int.

Your idea of using a regular function to convert back to `Time()` is right, but it might be nice to make it a classmethod so it's a little more obvious how it relates:

```
class Time(object):
    @classmethod
    def from_seconds(cls, seconds):
         _hours, _minutes, _seconds = ...
         return cls(_hours, _minutes, _seconds)
```

Comment: For the record, this is commonly called a *named constructor*.

Comment: You prob want to keep the `Time(object):` since we're all using new style classes nowadays :)

Comment: An alternative is to write your primary constructor to take more than one kind of input.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This is interesting. I'll try to familiarize with more with it.

Comment: well, I guessed that `__int__` meant that ferhtgoldaraz was using python 3.  Yes, in python 2 this method is called `__index__`, and make sure to inherit from `object` in those cases.